# what is the best code,script,module or package for read data from a web service?

Tags: php, web-services

I want to read web service data from a website and display it into my website.

i have these data:

- address: WebService/TsePublic.asmx
- service name : InstrumentDetailOneIns
- input parameters :UserName,Password,CIsin

is there any available code for use?

Comment: What kind of web service is that exactly?

Comment: Thats a very, very big question! Its kinda like asking what car is best for driving on roads… Personally I love using the Ruby programming language because it can be very quick to write what I need. Can you be more specific as to what environment you're working in? Are you working on your server (in which case PHP or Ruby will be a good bet) or on the clientside? (in which case Javascript is probably the best way forward)

Comment: i want working on server side.
my program is php.
is these information enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has a native [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) extension. Failing that I would recommend the open-source [nuSoap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/files/nusoap/0.7.3/nusoap-0.7.3.zip/download) package.

Answer (score 1):

I see from the tags you are using PHP. The webservice you are talking about is .NET, you could use something similar as: http://randompost.ca/random/php-calling-c-net-webservice/
to get it to work.

Comment: thanks a lot.
your guide is very useful.